# angular material typography - customisation

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular-material-theming

In customizing my [angular material theme's typography](https://material.angular.io/guide/typography). I understand that one can override the default font with their own font like so:

```
$custom-typography: mat-typography-config(
  $font-family: 'Lato, monospace'
);
```

Although, I noticed that [the source code](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/core/typography/_typography.scss) shows two fonts , the default Roboto, and then Helvetica is also included in inverted commas:

```
$font-family: 'Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif',
```

Is that a secondary font? I would like if I could choose a secondary font. If this is not a secondary font, what is it?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `font-family` property can hold several font names as a "fallback" system. If the browser does not support the first font, it tries the next font.

Start with the font you want, and always end with a generic family, to let the browser pick a similar font in the generic family, if no other fonts are available.

**Note:** Separate each value with a comma.

**Note:** If a font name contains white-space, it must be quoted. Single quotes must be used when using the "style" attribute in HTML.

Copied from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-family.asp)